# Display only first n associated records - Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :pictures
end

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :car
end
```

In one of my views, I want to display the first 8 pictures.

I have the following, but not sure if this is the best way of doing it

```
# simplified...
<% @car.pictures.each_with_index do |p,i| %>
    <%= p.image.url %>
    <% break if i == 7 %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<% @car.pictures.limit(8).each do |p| %>
  <%= p.image.url %>
<% end %>
```